# RapidMiner 5 - Export job to runnable standalone?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, rapidminer

Is there a way for the open source version of RapidMiner to export a process to an executable Java stand-alone file?
What I need is to deploy a process to a linux server, where it is executed regulary by a scheduler without the GUI, in batch mode.

There is something for the commercial version, RapidMiner Server, but didn't find something comparable for the open source version.

Can this be done somehow for with open source version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by myself, that would be http://sourceforge.net/projects/rapidanalytics/